# Possible for baseUri to be dynamic based on where raml was served

Tags: raml

Just getting started with raml (read the spec) to see if it has what I need to document my api.

Concerned about required baseUri property at root level to define you server Url. I am in a scenario in which my api is served out over many different domains.

Is it possible to define the baseUril as the url from which the raml doc was served?

Just looking at the spec I did not see a way. Of course there are probably  number of ways I could scrub the raml doc before deploy, or include the right domain raml file that has a variable defined for that particular deployment. But I would really like to avoid that.

Comment: I haven't found any workaround for this. Basically, the `baseURI` property of RAML forces me to serve it as a dynamic templated resource, using different rendering techniques depending on the language/platform...

Comment: Did you found any workaround for this? I have some problem and I want to know if you manage to resolve it. Thanks.